# Can I use a certificate authority with Elgamal encryption?

Tags: public-key, elgamal-encryption, certificates

Can I use a certificate authority with Elgamal encryption? Is this type of keys in CA?

Answer (score 1):

Certificate Authorities (CAs) don't do encryption. They sign Certificate Signing Requests (CSRs) and some additional data (dates, authority ID, allowed uses, etc) to produce a Certificate. That certificate is the CA's attestation that the Subject's public key in the certificate is legitimately owned by that Subject. Certificates are then used for signing things by the Subject (eg signing a TLS handshake or code signing depending on the allowed uses in the certificate).

Comment: ok thx for your answer. in my project, I want to use the certificate authority and the universal re-encryption for mixnets El Gamal. but I found a problem: the re-encryption el Gamal generates the keys .  and when i use the CA , it will give me the keys . then there will be a problem here . that's why i ask this question

Comment: Universal Mixnets with re-encryption don't work with standard ElGamal AFAIK. They certainly don't use certificates.